# Partial derivatives of multivariable parametric function

Tags: calculus, parametric, differential

If
$f\left( \vec{v} \left( s,t,r\right)  \right)  =p\left( x,y,z\right)  \vec{i} +q\left( x,y,z\right)  \vec{j} +u\left( x,y,z\right)  \vec{k}$

$x=x\left( s,t,r\right)$
$y=y\left( s,t,r\right)$
$z=z\left( s,t,r\right)$

We have a multivariable vector-valued function (takes inputs as vectors too) where:

The input space (parameters) is a 3D in $\left( s,t,r\right)$

The intermediate space is a 3D in $\left( x,y,z\right)$

The output space is a 3D in $\left( p,q,u\right)$

I wanna get the derivative of f ... I thought of the following as the
Partial derivative of f() w.r.t (s)

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial s} =  \left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} &\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial q}{\partial y} &\frac{\partial q}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \end{matrix} \right]\  .\left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \\ \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} \end{matrix} \right]  $

3x3 matrix multiplied by a vector (3x1) and the  result is a 3 element vector (3x1)

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} =\left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} .\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} +\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} .\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} +\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} .\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} \\ \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} +\frac{\partial q}{\partial y} .\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} +\frac{\partial q}{\partial z} .\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} .\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} .\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} .\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} \end{matrix} \right]  $

Is that correct?
And can we similarly find $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ and $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ ?

Is there a compact form for the rule?

Can we use the following notation?

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} =\triangledown f.\frac{\partial }{\partial s} \left[ \begin{matrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{matrix} \right]  =\left[ \begin{matrix}p\\ q\\ u\end{matrix} \right]  \left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} &\frac{\partial }{\partial y} &\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \end{matrix} \right]  .\frac{\partial }{\partial s} \left[ \begin{matrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{matrix} \right] $

As in simpler forms:

if

$f\left( \vec{v} \left( t\right)  \right)  =f\left( x,y\right)$

$\vec{v} \left( t\right)  =\left[ \begin{matrix}x\left( t\right)  \\ y\left( t\right)  \end{matrix} \right]  $

Then

$\frac{d}{dt} f\left( \vec{v} \left( t\right)  \right)  =\triangledown f.\frac{d}{dt} \vec{v} \left( t\right) = \left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \end{matrix} \right]  .\left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{dx}{dt} \\ \frac{dy}{dt} \end{matrix} \right] =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} .\frac{dx}{dt} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} .\frac{dy}{dt}   $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is just the general form of the "*chain rule*". It can be written in a slightly more compact notation. You can put all the derivatives into one Jacobian matrix:

$$ D(f \circ \vec{v}) = Df \cdot D \vec{v} =
 \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \\ 
\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial q}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial q}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin {pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}
\end {pmatrix} =
\begin {pmatrix}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial q}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial q}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
\end {pmatrix}
$$

What you wrote is just looking at one column of $D \vec{v}$ at a time.

Comment: Thanks Nick. That’s great! I haven’t studied Jacobian matrix yet and that means my logic is correct 